# Разбитие файла подключения к postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Хочу разбить файл подлючения к `postgresql`.

В файле `src/db/database.js/ хочу экспортировать файл`config.js`:

```
"use strict";

import { Pool } from 'pg';
import config from './../config';

export default new Pool(
    config.db.database,
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.details
);
```

В самом файле `config.js` будет данные о подключении:

```
'use strict';

export default config;

config.db = {
    user: 'postgres',
    password: '047',
    database: 'Users',
};

config.db.details = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres'
};

config.keys = {
    secret: '/jVdf='
};
```

Выдает ошибку `var _default = config;`. Что я сделал не правильно?

Comment: не изобретай велосипед, используй [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.js`, в вашем случае, должен выглядеть так:

```
'use strict';

export default {
   db: {
     user: 'postgres',
     password: '047',
     database: 'Users',
     details: {
       host: '127.0.0.1',
       port: 5432,
       dialect: 'postgres'
     }
   },
   keys: {
     secret: '/jVdf='
   }
}
```